# Win Phone 8.1 deployment issues to device -0x8103012B

Tags: windows-phone-8, win-phone-silverlight-8.1

I amtrying to run win phone app on my device (win phone 8.1) and it throws error 0x8103012B. My device is unlocked for development and I have developer account setup as well. Any pointers to this would be great. thanks in advance!

Errors:

```
2>Connecting to Device...
2>Optimizing for device...
2>Installing the application...
2>Deployment of application to device failed.
2>0x8103012B
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: your device os windows 8 or 8.1?

Comment: Phone device OS is win 8.1.  but my laptop device used to create is windows 8.0. Could this be an issue? Now I am trying to deploy from 8.1 laptop to rule out this possibility

Comment: your laptop os not issue but which sdk Install 8 Or 8.1?

Comment: Got the solution for this one. My phone was company enrolled (via settings - workplace) which was preventing it to deploy apps. After updating publisher name to appropriate name  it worked.

Comment: Application Deployment Registration your Device?